# Data Retention in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration

I need to implement data retention in our SQL Server database. Other than archival tables, do we have any other options? Please suggest

Comment: Sure there are options. You could look into partitioning or if persisting all the data is important maybe consider not deleting it from your table. This question is really too broad.

Comment: Yes, I have did research on partition as well, but didn't get much performance. so I am looking for other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on the nature of the data (size/need for immediacy/business case) a bit but a few common patterns for retention include:

1. archive tables
2. aggregation tables
3. server replication
4. scheduled instance backups
5. advanced magic (partitions/column storage etc)

Without knowing the data or objectives a case could be made for any of these.